# Optimizing Post-processing Workflow with FFmpeg for Janus Playrecord Plugin

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video, process, speed

I hope you’re all doing well. I have a question regarding the post-processing of recorded files using the Janus playrecord plugin. Currently, after the recording is done, I end up with two .mjr files (one for audio and one for video) and a .nfo file. To post-process these files, I’ve created a bash script that checks if the .nfo file exists and then utilizes the Janus janus-pp-rec tool to convert the audio (.mjr) file to opus format and the video (.mjr) file to .webm format. Finally, I used a ffmpeg command to merge the audio (.opus) and video (.webm) into one file named “recording(.webm).”

However, post-processing is proving to be quite time-consuming. For example, a 5-minute recording takes about 1 minute to complete the post-processing, and a 1-hour recording takes approximately 11 minutes. I want the post-processing to be done on the fly while the recorded files (.mjr) are still being written, has this been done before?

I have tried increasing the threads from 1 to 4 but it still did not improve the ffmpeg merging of the .webs and opus files.

The janus-pp-rec tool is converting the files quickly, but how can I speed up the ffmpeg part?

I’d greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have on how to achieve a more efficient post-processing workflow. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the ffmpeg command you use?